# How to create object from array object and pass it to the object instance

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, javascript-objects

I have an array that contains several members. Then I created a new instance of a MemberValue object in which I passed this array called "name" as a value but it passed all the values as a single string.

```
var name = ["1.K", "2.K"];
var filterValue = new data.MemberValue({
  MemberName : "R.K",
  hierarchyName: "xyz", 
  levelName: name,  
  uniqueName: name,
  levelDepth:1,
  memberKind:"Regular"
});
```

The output we are getting in the console is

```
0:{MemberName : "R.K",
  hierarchyName: "xyz", 
  levelName: ["1.K", "2.K"], 
  uniqueName: ["1.K", "2.K"], 
  levelDepth:1,
  memberKind:"Regular"}
```

But we need output like this

```
0:{MemberName : "R.K",
  hierarchyName: "xyz", 
  levelName: "1.K",  
  uniqueName: "1.K", 
  levelDepth:1,
  memberKind:"Regular"}
1:{MemberName : "R.K",
  hierarchyName: "xyz", 
  levelName: "2.K",  
  uniqueName: "2.K", 
  levelDepth:1,
  memberKind:"Regular"}
```

Can anybody help me with this how we can convert array object as object and pass them into the instance of object that I have created.

I have tried with .map function but that not works for me

Comment: what is MemberValue? is it come from special library or you define it in your project?

Comment: it looks like you just want a `map()` over the `name` array: `var filterValue = name.map((n) => new data.MemberValue({ ... levelName: n, uniqueName: n, ...}));`

Comment: @eureka MemberValue is the predefined constructor that initializes a new instance of a MemberValue object:

Comment: this MemberValue doesn't pass any index as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the entire `name` array to the `MemberValue` when you need to iterate over the array and call `MemberValue` for each string in the `name` array, and stick the `MemberValues` results in their own array:

```js
class MemberValue {
  constructor(Member) {
    this.MemberName = Member['MemberName'];
    this.hierarchyName = Member['hierarchyName'];
    this.levelName = Member['levelName'];
    this.uniqueName = Member['uniqueName'];
    this.levelDepth = Member['levelDepth'];
    this.memberKind = Member['memberKind'];
  }
}

let name = ["1.K", "2.K"];
var memberValues = [];

for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
  var filterValue = new MemberValue({
    MemberName: "R.K",
    hierarchyName: "xyz",
    levelName: name[i],
    uniqueName: name[i],
    levelDepth: 1,
    memberKind: "Regular"
  });
  memberValues.push(filterValue);
}

console.log(memberValues);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100%!important;
}
```

If you want to do it with the `.map` function, you can do it like this:

```js
class MemberValue {
  constructor(Member) {
    this.MemberName = Member['MemberName'];
    this.hierarchyName = Member['hierarchyName'];
    this.levelName = Member['levelName'];
    this.uniqueName = Member['uniqueName'];
    this.levelDepth = Member['levelDepth'];
    this.memberKind = Member['memberKind'];
  }
}

const name = ["1.K", "2.K"];

var memberValues = name.map(function(nameValue) {
  return new MemberValue({
    MemberName : "R.K",
    hierarchyName: "xyz", 
    levelName: nameValue,  
    uniqueName: nameValue,
    levelDepth:1,
    memberKind:"Regular"
  });
});

console.log(memberValues);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100%!important;
}
```

Comment: When am I using the above two methods, giving me an error Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: I added code snippets with some help @Nikkkshit's `MemberValue` class definition.

Answer (score 0):

- I have just created class of `MemberValue`, to replicate your code.
- You are directly assigning hole array to `levelName` and `uniqueName`, that's why the value is comming hole array and not an individual value.
- to get individual value from `name`, you can loop thourgh it using `map()`, method of array and return a new object of `MemberValue` class to get array of object.

```js
class MemberValue {
  constructor(MemberName, hierarchyName, levelName, uniqueName, levelDepth, memberKind) {
    this.MemberName = MemberName;
    this.hierarchyName = hierarchyName;
    this.levelName = levelName;
    this.uniqueName = uniqueName;
    this.levelDepth = levelDepth;
    this.memberKind = memberKind;
  }
}
let name = ["1.K", "2.K"];
let filterValue = name.map(val => {
  return new MemberValue(
    "R.K",
    "xyz",
    val,
    val,
    1,
    "Regular"
  );
})
console.log(filterValue);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100%!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the array using any array method and substitute the name to the relevant property.

```
var array = ["1.K", "2.K"];
    
var sampleData = {
   MemberName : "R.K",
   hierarchyName: "xyz", 
   levelName: name,  
   uniqueName: name,
   levelDepth:1,
   memberKind:"Regular"
};

var result = array.map(function(itemName) {
    var data = {...sampleData}
    data.levelName = itemName;
    data.uniqueName = itemName;
    return data;
});
console.log(result);
```